# How do I change the footnote symbols (asterisk, daggers) to numbers?

Tags: symbols, numbering, footnotes

I simply want my footnotes to use numbers rather than symbols (which for some reason is the default behaviour for an `article`. I would also like the horizontal line to extend the width of the page. How do I do this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel} % formatting rules for the English language
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % proper formatting for accented characters and non-standard characters such as pipelines
\usepackage[top=33mm, bottom=38mm, left=26mm, right=20mm]{geometry} % page layout
\usepackage{lmodern} % font formatting
\usepackage{float} % allow floating environments such as figures
\usepackage{amsmath} % math eqn formatting
\usepackage{amssymb} % math fonts

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}} % this doesn't even fix it

\title{\bf{PROJECT}}
\author{NAME.\footnote{Student}}
\date{\today}

\maketitle

\vfill

\begin{abstract}
Abstract here
\end{abstract}

\clearpage
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\end{document}
```

Comment: Footnotes to the title or authors are treated differently than those in the body, because they're usually meant for acknowledgments or data relative to the author.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Footnotes to the title or authors are treated differently than those in the body, because they're usually meant for acknowledgments or data relative to the author.
You can redefine `\maketitle` not to do that and use the standard `\footnote` mechanism.

For the footnote rule to use the whole text width, another command must be redefined.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[
  top=33mm,
  bottom=38mm,
  left=26mm,
  right=20mm
]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter % access to internal commands
%% redefine \maketitle to use the normal \footnote mechanism
\renewcommand\maketitle{\par
  \begingroup
    \if@twocolumn
      \ifnum \col@number=\@ne
        \@maketitle
      \else
        \twocolumn[\@maketitle]%
      \fi
    \else
      \newpage
      \global\@topnum\z@   % Prevents figures from going at top of page.
      \@maketitle
    \fi
    \thispagestyle{plain}\@thanks
  \endgroup
  \global\let\maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@author\@empty
  \global\let\@date\@empty
  \global\let\@title\@empty
  \global\let\title\relax
  \global\let\author\relax
  \global\let\date\relax
  \global\let\and\relax
}

%% redefine \footnoterule for using the whole text width
\renewcommand\footnoterule{%
  \kern-3\p@\hrule\@width\columnwidth\kern 2.6\p@
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\title{PROJECT}
\author{NAME\footnote{Student}}
\date{\today}

\maketitle

\vfill

\begin{abstract}
Abstract here
\end{abstract}

\clearpage
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please, note that `\bf` has been deprecated (together with all the two letter font changing commands such as `\it` or `\tt`) for about twenty years. Use `\textbf` instead, if you really want a boldface title.